# How to store JSON object into multi-dimension array

Tags: objective-c

I want to store JSON Object into multi-dimension array.

```
appDelegate.serviceIdArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"services_id"];
appDelegate.nameArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"services_name"];
appDelegate.rateArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"rate"];
appDelegate.sortDetailArray= [response1 valueForKey:@"short_desc"];
appDelegate.longDetailArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"long_desc"];
appDelegate.imageArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"image"];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: hello!! i want to store all array into one array,multi-dimension array i want to store all json object into one-array,i have store each object into different array but i want to store in one-muti-dimension array.

Comment: Still not clear, please edit your question to be more clear. Please add what do you have, what do you want and what is your problem.

Comment: Hello!! i want to store [response1 valueForKey:@"services_id"],[response1 valueForKey:@"services_name"],[response1 valueForKey:@"rate"],[response1 valueForKey:@"short_desc"],[response1 valueForKey:@"long_desc"],[response1 valueForKey:@"image"] all this value into single(multi-dimensionarray)array,i have used differnt array but now i need to use single array for all value

Comment: Please edit your question, no one understand it like that.

Comment: You mean like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[response1 valueForKey:@"services_id"],[response1 valueForKey:@"services_name"],[response1 valueForKey:@"rate"],[response1 valueForKey:@"short_desc"],[response1 valueForKey:@"long_desc"],[response1 valueForKey:@"image"], nil]` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *multiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *serviceIdArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"services_id"];
if( serviceIdArray )
{
    [multiArray addObject:serviceIdArray];
}
NSArray *nameArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"services_name"];
if( nameArray )
{
    [multiArray addObject:nameArray];
}
NSArray *rateArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"rate"];
if( rateArray )
{
    [multiArray addObject:rateArray];
}
NSArray *sortDetailArray= [response1 valueForKey:@"short_desc"];
if( sortDetailArray )
{
    [multiArray addObject:sortDetailArray];
}
NSArray *longDetailArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"long_desc"];
if( longDetailArray )
{
    [multiArray addObject:longDetailArray];
}
NSArray *imageArray = [response1 valueForKey:@"image"];
if( imageArray )
{
    [multiArray addObject:imageArray];
}

...
//do whatever you want with the multi-dimension array
[multiArray release];
```

Answer (score 0):

use [SBJSONs](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) . in that you can user [object JSONRepresentation] which is converting an json String to an NSMutableDictionary !

Comment: I gather he already has the parsed JSON.  Doesn't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite simple, all you need to do is create an `NSArray` and call `addObject` with your current arrays.

```
NSArray *myarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:array1,array2,array3,nil];
```

That will do the trick